# How does one obtain PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights to a running process?

Tags: windows-10, c++, winapi

I have made (ok copy/pasted) a hack to the game, AssualtCube. Part of the hack involves using OpenProcess() to get a handle with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights to ac_client.exe. This works fine in Visual Studio's integrated debugger but it fails, producing ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when run as an external build. If I have PROCEESS_ALL_ACCESS rights in visual studio, there should be a way to get those rights outside of Visual Studio. I am already running as admin.

Comment: From help **To open a handle to another process and obtain full access rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Changing Privileges in a Token.** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights

Answer (score 0):

From help *To open a handle to another process and obtain full access rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Changing Privileges in a Token.*

This uses WMI to enable the privilege. Most privileges a user has are disabled and need to be enabled in code for the program to use it.

The example uses `localhost`. `ComputerName = "."` means current computer.

```
'CreateRemoteProcess.vbs
'Starts a program on a remote computer using WMI.
'Programs started on remote computers are invisible on that computer unlike programs started locally
ComputerName = "127.0.0.1"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Debug,Shutdown)}\\" & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
intReturn = objProcess.Create("c:\windows\notepad", Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
If intReturn = 0 then
    wscript.echo "PID is " & intProcessID
Else
    Msg = "Error code " & intReturn & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
    Msg = Msg & "2   Access denied" & vbcrlf
    Msg = Msg & "3   Insufficient privilege" & vbcrlf
    Msg = Msg & "8   Unknown failure" & vbcrlf
    Msg = Msg & "9   Path not found" & vbcrlf
    Msg = Msg & "21  Invalid parameter" 
    wscript.echo Msg
End If
```

PS: This needs to be run as admin and non admins do not have SeDebug to be enabled.